# Error when trying to sync iPod touch

Tags: 10.10, ipod

I have been trying to get my iPod touch to sync on Ubuntu 10.10. Every time I plug my iPod in my computer this error come up and says "Unhandeled Lockdown error-4" I use iOS 5 and I still can't get it to work. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but perhaps the software library libimobiledevice needs to get updated for the recently released iOS 5.

See the bug report on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/795475

There seems to be a patch for this:
https://code.launchpad.net/~om26er/ubuntu/maverick/libimobiledevice/fix-iOS5-support

See:
http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_iPod_managers

Comment: I looked at the links you gave me but I can't seem to download the patch to fix this....